# Java accessing to Map in Queue<Map>

Tags: java, object, dictionary, queue

I'm trying to figure out how can I add some data into this :

```
Map<String, Queue<Map<Integer, MyObject>>> map1 = new HashMap<String, Queue<Map<Integer, MyObject>>>();
```

I have been trying things like that :

```
map1.put(login, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Map<MyObject>>(500, true);
```

But I guess i'm totally wrong, and I would love some tips and further explanations.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
map1.put(login, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Map<Integer, MyObject>>(500, true));
                                           ^^^^^^^                       ^(missing closing bracket)
```

See that you are missing the Integer type in map. If you wish to add value to Queue then you could do something like:

```
Map<Integer, MyObject> myMap = ...;
myMap.put(1, new MyObject...);
map1.get(login).add(myMap);//or can use offer
```

Answer (score 3):

You have missed the `Integer` type-parameter for the `Map`.

```
map1.put(login, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Map<Integer, MyObject>>(500, true));
```

If you're working with Java7+, you can actually skip the implicit type-parameters and rely on Java's [type-inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) features, which is helpful for producing readable code:

```
map1.put(login, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(500, true));
```